# Render Component into summary row

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I efficiently render a component into the grid's summary row?

The summaryRenderer only returns the raw value, which is then put into the template. So this is my summary renderer:

```
summaryRenderer:function(summaryValue, values, dataIndex) {
    return summaryValue + '<br><div id="btn-' + dataIndex + '">';
}
```

And somehow I have to insert a component after the renderer is through. I have tried to do it in store.load callback, but the renderer is done only after the load.

```
me.getStore().load({
  callback:function(records, operation, success) {
    Ext.each(me.getColumns(),function(column) {
      Ext.create('Ext.Button',{
        text:'Use this column',
        handler:function() {
          me.createEntryFromColumn(column);
        }
      }).render('btn-'+column.dataIndex);
      // throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null", 
      // because the div is not yet in the dom.
    });     
  }
});
```

Which event can I attach to, that is fired only after the summaryRenderer is through?

Comment: May be wait for the `refresh` event of the table? Can you set up a fiddle we can play around with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it this way:

```
init: function () {
    this.control({
        'myGrid': {
            afterrender: this.doStuff
        }
    });
},

doStuff: function (myGrid) {
    var self = this;

    myGrid.getStore().on({
        load: function (store, records) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });

    myGrid.getStore().load();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check at : Component Template (http://skirtlesden.com/ux/ctemplate)  for the component rendering.

I did not check myself, but just looking in the code:  https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/Column2.html#Ext-grid-column-Column-method-initComponent (ExtJs 6.0.1), you can see that the summary is render via a function.
See in `initComponent`

```
me.setupRenderer('summary');
```

Then in `setupRenderer`

```
// Set up the correct property: 'renderer', 'editRenderer', or 'summaryRenderer'
me[me.rendererNames[type]] = me.bindFormatter(format);
```

And `bindFormatter` produce a function.

So I suppose, you can extend column, and extend `initComponent`, after the `this.callParent()`, you can override `me[me.rendererNames[type]]` and put your own function which take v (the value) in parameter and which return the product of a CTemplate.
Something like

```
me["summaryRenderer"] = function(v) { return ctpl.apply({component:c, value:v})}
```

I think @CD.. suggestion to set a fiddle is a good idea.